# Gremlin: toLowerCase() not working properly

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I have a vertex called 'city' that has property [cityName] "Miami" and property [syonyms] "Miami^Magic City^Little Cuba".

The following query returns no results:

```
g.V().hasLabel('city').has('syonyms',filter{it.get().toLowerCase().contains('Miami')})
```

While this query gives me the results that I want:

```
g.V().hasLabel('city').has('syonyms',filter{it.get().toLowerCase().contains('miami')})
```

I thought that the "toLowerCase()" would convert "Miami" into all lower case, but it doesn't seem to be doing that. Any ideas?

Comment: toLowerCase() looks to be applied in the right way to the content of get(). So Miami becomes miami and it can only match on contains("miami").

Comment: yes, but as described above it is working in the opposite way. If you notice, the "syonyms" property for "Miami" is  "Miami^Magic City^Little Cuba", where "miami" is capitalized.

Comment: "Miami" is "Miami^Magic City^Little Cuba" is lowered cased calling toLowerCase on it, it becames "miami is "miami^magic city^lttle cuba" that contains "miami".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding toLowerCase() at the end of the value within "contains" solved the issue.

```
g.V().hasLabel('city').has('syonyms',filter{it.get().toLowerCase().contains('Miami'.toLowerCase())})
```